# Understanding SwitchMap in rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs6, switchmap

as per the definition of the switchMap

> On each emission the previous inner observable (the result of the
>   function you supplied) is cancelled and the new observable is
>   subscribed. You can remember this by the phrase switch to a new
>   observable.

now, i have a code like this

```
const source = timer(0, 5000).pipe(map(x=>`${x}`));
const example = source.pipe(switchMap((f) => interval(1000).pipe(map(y=>`f${f}-s${y}`))),take(20));
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val+' '+ new Date().getSeconds()));
```

and the result is this

[image]

my question is,

1. 25th second - the outer function is called and the inner function is not yet triggered, so the latest value of the outer function is 0 and inner function is also 0 as a default one because it has no value yet **f0-s0 25**
2. 26th second - the inner function is called and the value ideally should be 0 as the function is just called first time but it is 1 ie. **f0-s1 26**
3. 30th second - the outer function is called which resets the inner function value to 0, ie. **f1-s0 30**
4. why is the inner function got reset on the 35th second, it is still 1 second remaining

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-fwcap5?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=60)

i find it very difficult to understand the concept, thank you

Comment: Apart from @martin 's answer explaining gaps on `34s` and `39s`, I think, you're also wrongly assuming that your source started emitting at `25`th second, while it started at `24s`. Theres no "default 0", it is source starting at `24s` and interval first emitting at `25s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you're wrongly assuming that your source started emitting at `25s` second, while it started at `24s`. And theres no "default 0".

Source emits at `t0`, then in `1s` inner `interval` will emit. Inner `interval` will have 5 seconds to emit 4 **or** 5 times, before you'll switch to another value from the source `timer`. If your source `timer` started emitting at `24s`, then first value you'll get on the subscription is at `25s` — when the `interval` will emit its first value.

The reason for 4 **or** 5 time is in RxJS and JS scheduling. See this [stackblitz for a rough example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-p1zw5g) of what might be going on. Explaining this in detail would take **more research effort and time**.

Heres a marble diagram picturing `mergeMap vs exhaustMap vs switchMap vs concatMap` behavior to get a better understanding:

[image: mergeMap vs exhaustMap vs switchMap vs concatMap]

Check this [mergeMap vs exhaustMap vs switchMap vs concatMap playground](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/mergeMap-vs-exhaustMap-vs-switchMap-vs-concatMap/).

Comment: all your examples using marbles were very helpful, thank you

Answer (score 7):

This is because RxJS by default for async actions uses `setTimeout` and `setInterval` function that don't guarantee they'll make exactly the timeout you want.

So if you use timeouts `5000` and `1000` then it's not guaranteed which of the actions will happen first after 5s. Sometimes the outer Observable emits first and sometimes the inner emits first but `switchMap` can't do anything about it.

You can see how different the times can get with eg. this:

```
const start = new Date().getTime();
setInterval(() => console.log(new Date().getTime() - start), 1000);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-urep5j

```
1004
2001
3002
4000
4998
...
```

So sometimes the delay is `1004` and other times just `998`.

Comment: so in switchMap whenever the outer functions get called the inner functions value get reset, is my understanding right? if possible, could you make a marbles tom help people understand about switchMap, one like this?https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/cca5146802c43c401e4742c7b6e96340

Comment: @LijinDurairaj This shows what `switchMap` does http://reactivex.io/rxjs/img/switchMap.png

Comment: i just found out this, https://rxmarbles.com/#switchMap, according to this marble, the switchMap only emits a value when the outer function emits a value and it resets the entire inner function value, is my understanding correct, please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I think, particular issue here is not in the JS scheduler missing 1s interval, but rather in the way RxJS interchangeably using `setInterval` and `setTimer` and the way these async tasks are prioritized in the JS env. When JS scheduler checks its task list -- it will run **all** timers and intervals that were set, **but the order of the execution will rely on the way and time they were set**. Heres a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-p1zw5g) where order is swapped on consequent calls

Comment: @LijinDurairaj, "resetting inner function" is not the best way to think of `switchMap`. All `__Map` operators substitute value on source stream with a stream of values, returned by inner function. The difference is in reaction to subsequent values on source stream. `switchMap` will unsubscribe from previously swapped stream and use the new one, generated by inner function.